# Apache2 barfing on C++ CGI script due to "undefined symbol"

Tags: c++, apache2, cgi

Apache2 has been failing to execute software that executes just fine at the command line. The relevant bit of the error log is:

undefined symbol: allocatePropIOBuffer

The relevant line in the C++ source is:

unsigned char *allocatePropIOBuffer(SWISH *sw, unsigned long buf_needed)

Since I don't know a lick of C++ I'm at a loss at how to fix this in the source code. Any ideas?

Comment: At a guess apache is loading a different set of shared libraries to your command line execution

Comment: So how do I make sure apache2 sees the same libraries? I've been googling like mad and still don't have a solution. \